# AWS Lambda Node module version mismatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was following the AWS Lambda tutorial on [automating deployments of Lambda-based applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html) and have uploaded a simple lambda function to AWS via CodePipeline and CloudFormation, but am getting the following error while trying to run my lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46.",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "bindings (/var/task/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/time/index.js:8:35)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)"
  ]
}
```

The contents of my lambda function are as follows...

samTemplate.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Outputs the time
Resources:
  TimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ./
      Events:
        MyTimeApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /TimeResource
            Method: GET
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install time
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket <redacted> 
                                   --output-template-file NewSamTemplate.yaml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - NewSamTemplate.yaml
```

and index.js

```
var time = require('time');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var currentTime = new time.Date(); 
    currentTime.setTimezone("America/Los_Angeles");
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: '200',
        body: 'The time in Los Angeles is: ' + currentTime.toString(),
    });
};
```

On the AWS page of the Lambda function I do have NodeJS 6.10 set as the runtime, so I'm confused why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the build step, I was using Node v4 (by the tutorial's guidance) when it should have been v6. Check your build step matches the Node version your lambda function is using!

Comment: Can you show exactly where or how you incorrectly specified your node version as 4? Which file contained this info? etc.?

Comment: @dashmug In the CodeBuild project -> Environment -> Runtime/Runtime Version. See screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/4LlJH . The AWS Tutorial for setting up CodePipeline with Lambda here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html  is incorrect on Step 2.10 where it says "In Version choose `aws/codebuild/nodejs:4.3.2`" because earlier in Step 1 -> "Add a samTemplate.yaml file..." the provided YAML file states Runtime: nodejs6.10  so you should use `aws/codebuild/nodejs:6.3.1` in Step 2.10 instead.

Comment: I'm asking for the sake of future readers. You should put that in your answer and not as a comment as it is harder to read.